# How can I programmatically click kendo treeview node

Tags: triggers, click, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

How can I programmaticaly click kendo treeview node" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some good information on the [Kendo API reference](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-select)

Here's an excerpt on how to programmatically select a node.

> Select the node with HTML id="firstItem"
>
> ```
> var treeView = $("#treeView").data("kendoTreeView");
> treeView.select($("#firstItem"));
> ```
>
> Select the first node in the treeview
>
> ```
> var treeView = $("#treeView").data("kendoTreeView");
> treeView.select(".k-item:first");
> ```